# not found: value scalaJSModuleKind

Tags: scala, scala.js

I am facing this issue when upgrading scala-js from 0.6.x to 1.x.x, and the issue is that I have the following code in the build.sbt:-

```
scalaJSModuleKind in Test := ModuleKind.CommonJSModule
```

when I load sbt then I get this error:-

```
error: not found: value scalaJSModuleKind
scalaJSModuleKind in Test := ModuleKind.CommonJSModule
^
```

same code runs with scala-js 0.6.x but not with 1.x.x.

can somebody help me in achieving the same thing or to fix this with scala-js 1.x.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the release notes of Scala.js 1.0.0 explain](https://www.scala-js.org/news/2020/02/25/announcing-scalajs-1.0.0/#preparations-before-upgrading-from-06x), you have to make sure to use `scalaJSLinkerConfig` instead of, among others, `scalaJSModuleKind`. In this case you will need

```scala
scalaJSLinkerConfig in Test ~= { _.withModuleKind(ModuleKind.CommonJSModule) }
```